# How to expose data from database to be queryable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I need to design a wrapper around a few database tables, allowing the client to simply execute a *GET*:

```
http://myservice/accounts?$filter=name eq alex
```

And then this service will apply that query against a database table like:

```
create table account (name varchar, key int)
```

We would have some controller that would grab that query string and apply it against the dataset, in pseudocode:

```
public class AccountsController
{
   public HttpResponseMessage Get()
   {
        return _dataSource.Get(Request.ODataQueryString);
    }
}
```

**How do we expose a sql server table to be easily queryable via odata?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using EntityFramework, you'd just need to register your controller as an OData endpoint, decorate it with the OData `[EnableQuery]` attribute and return an instance of the class you're targeting via your controller method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint